# Website -> Excel -> Excel

Tags: excel, vba

A little background to my question. I work for a company that is charged with retrieving data from databases from all 50 states and DC. I take this data and reformat it in excel. Once it's reformatted I use SQL Server to upload it to our website vetportal.agdata.net. While some states are not so bad, retrieving information from others make it very painful to sort through.

I have 2 questions:

1. Can a code be written so that a new database can be crossed checked with the old database (our records) and update the information in the old database while also excluding duplicate information?
2. Can a code be written to take a number from an open excel sheet, switch over to an open website, input the number, search for the individual, and extract his/her information, and finally update the excel with that information then move on to the next person? Ex, WA State's website is set up so that you can only look up one person at a time which is very tedious when going through 1200+ individuals.

I have some experience with C++ and have written programs that draw code from other files, but mainly only equations or values which then get evaluated in my code so I know this is a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you have a repetitive technological problem you can solve it with some programming.

Your questions:

1. You can make that with a little app, that using SQL reads the information from the new database and checks/updates the information of the old database.
2. This code is a little more difficult to do, but i guess it can be done. In C++, I don't know if there is any library that can already open Excel files, but in Java you have the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), that way you can open your excel file in the application, then while iterating through the information you open the website in the application, and submit the form you want with your number, getting the response and parsing it.

If you want to make this in Java I think it will not waste you too much time if you know C++ . The only exception is opening the website in java and parsing it which will take more time to learn and do.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes. Depending on the databases, you may be able to do a db to db connection. You could then write a query using an INNER JOIN to update information in the old database and exclude duplicates.

2) A few ways to approach this problem. Depending on your language (mine is PHP) you could use an open source class such as PHPExcel to open the sheet and fetch & update website data (cURL). You could also write some VBA within Excel that could do similar functionality.